# Internal working of stdin and input buffer

Tags: stdin, outputstream, gets

I m trying to print the number of characters entered by user within 5 seconds. But I m facing some problem in fetching the input buffer.

Code snippet

---

```
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# define INTERVAL 3
# define MAX_SIZE 1024

char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
int count = 0;

void alarm_handler (int i)
{
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("\nTimer expired.....\r\n");
    count = read(stdin,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    puts(buffer);
    printf("count:%d\r\n",strlen(buffer));
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM,alarm_handler); 
    alarm(INTERVAL);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("Start Triggering....\r\n");
    while (1)
    {
        gets(buffer);
    }
    return;
}
```

In the above code, I am not getting the input entered by an user and the output buffer is always zero. Could anyone please tell me what went wrong and a solution for
 it?

Output

```
++++++

Start Triggering....

akakakakakkaka

Timer expired.....

count:0
```

But I m expecting the below output

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Start Triggering....

akakakakakkaka

Timer expired.....

akakakakakkaka

count:14
```

Please suggest your views on this.

Comment: Welcome new user! Learn how to write code snippets... indent every line with four spaces, or insert `inline code` by surrounding with backticks. Makes things easier to read. For example your `#include` statements show up as **bold** because of the way the `#` symbol is interpreted...

Comment: One more point... you want to count "for five seconds" but set the INTERVAL to 3. I kept that value in the code below... but it's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering and things like that are quite complex. I took a slightly different approach to your problem - setting the terminal so keystrokes are passed to the program immediately (instead of waiting until `<enter>` is pressed), and counting the number of keys pressed as it happens.
This required using the function `getch()` which modifies the terminal setting. Note that I make sure the terminal is returned to its "old" setting at the end, just in case the interrupt happened "at the wrong time".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define INTERVAL 3

int count = 0;
int flag = 0;
struct termios oldt; // keep old terminal settings to restore at the end

// function prototype - compiler was complaining. Not sure why?
unsigned int alarm(unsigned int interval);

void alarm_handler(int i) {
  flag = 1;
}

int getch(void)
{
  // function to return keystroke "as it happens"
  int ch;
  struct termios newt;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt); /*store old settings */
  newt = oldt; /* copy old settings to new settings */
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); /* make one change to old settings in new settings */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt); /*apply the new settings immediatly */
  ch = getchar(); /* standard getchar call */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt); /*reapply the old settings */
  return ch; /*return received char */
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGALRM,alarm_handler); 
  alarm(INTERVAL);

  printf("Start Triggering....\r\n");
  char c;
  do
    {
      c = getch(); // get key as soon as it's pressed
      putchar(c);  // and echo to the screen
      count++;     // increment counter
    } while (!flag);

  printf("\nTimed out!\nCharacter count = %d\n", count);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt); /*reapply the old settings */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not come up with this version of getch() myself... I found it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/18395/ but I'm pretty sure that's not the original source either. May the original author consider him or herself thanked...